# Drawing ERD for this Sample Database

Tags: database, database-design, rdbms, erd

Consider a system where employee record is kept. The database should store employee name,department etc. Every employee has a reporting manager to whom he has to report.
There are 4 levels of employee –

1. Junior Engineer
2. Senior Engineer
3. Team Lead
4. Senior Team Lead

Every junior engineer has to report to Senior engineer. Every senior Developer has to report to team lead. Every team lead has to report to senior team lead.

I came to this idea:-

There will be two table

**1.Employee**

**2.Reporting**

`Employee table` would contain necessary information like EmployeeID,Employee Name,Department Name etc.; primary key is `EmployeeID`

`Reporting Table` would contain two columns EmployeeID and ReportingMangerID ;`EmployeeID` is foreign key related to Primarykey of Employee Table.

I dont know if I am correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the following is true:

- one employee reports to 0..1 other employees
- one employee has 0..n reports

Then you can have "manager" as an attribute for the employee table.

If the following is true:

- one employee reports to 0..n other employees
- one employee has 0..n reports

Then you need to have your structure.

Comment: I think First Condition is true.In that case no additional table is needed,right?

Comment: "manager" effectively becomes an attribute of "employee", so you don't need an extra table.

Comment: Since this question is marked `ERD`, note that in ER, an attribute is a mapping from an entity set to a value set, not from an entity set to an entity set. What you're describing is a denormalized relationship rather than an attribute.